# How do I prevent multiple module logout when one of them logs out?

Tags: php

I'm not so good in explaining my problems so if you find anything wrong I apologize for it.

So my problem is that in my web site I have 6 modules-super, manager, sales, cashier, technical support & client. If I open all of them in chrome or in firefox & login anyone of them it doesn't effect other modules. But when all of them are logged in & when I logout from one of them all of those modules logout.

This doesn't happen while login but why it happens while logout?

I cannot post my code, sorry.

Whatt should I do?

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention, but my website is running on localhost. Its not online.

Comment: So as you said you are not good at explaining but when some one does'nt know the situation he couldn't answer, You need to tell what concept of login method you use to verify for module access.\

Comment: They are different users?

Comment: You should add the code for the logout feature, otherwise it's just guessing what's wrong. You can remove sensitive data if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that you're storing a single login token for all sessions logged in and when the user logs out, that token is removed and revokes access for each browser. It would be better to set cookies to maintain login state.

Since I can't see your code, I can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm setting each session with a different name. For example, im manager module session is set as $_SESSION['manager'] same for other modules.
On logout I unset $_SESSION['manager'] and destroy it.

Comment: Are you storing the value of $_SESSION['manager'] in the database and then checking for it?

Comment: Yes, the value of $_SESSION['manager'] is the name of the manager who has logged in using his/her email & password. The email & password are then verified from the values stored DB in manager_login table. If a record is found, the managers name is stored in the $_SESSION['manager'] variable.
Same method is applied for other modules login as well.

Comment: So what happens when the user logs out? That value is removed from the DB right? It stands to reason that it would log out that person from everywhere.